# NHibernate collection loading, "illegal access to loading collection"

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem loading a collection. Setup I have is simple one-to-many association, mapped using FluentNHibernate. Entity is loaded withough exception being thrown, but accessing related collection displays "*illegal access to loading collection*". I'll paste relevant part of code here.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Department : Entity
{
    ...
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<PressJobRun> PressJobRun
    {
        get { return pressJobRunField; }
        protected set { pressJobRunField = value; }
    }
    ...
}
```

mapped as follows

```
public DepartmentMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name)
        .Not.Nullable()
        .Length(100);
    HasMany(x => x.PressJobRun)
        .AsBag()
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .LazyLoad()
        .BatchSize(50);
    ...
}
```

I've also tried to disable lazy loading, by excluding the line and by calling `.Not.LazyLoad()`, however end is the same.

```
    using (var tx = m_Repository.Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var depts = m_Repository.Session.CreateCriteria<Department>().List<Department>();
        var dept = depts[0];
        ...
    }
```

I realize exposing Session is not the thing to do, but this was in attempts to make sure that session is open.

When I drill down the exception I see following stack trace:

```
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Initialize(Boolean writing)
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Read()
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ReadSize()
   at NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag.get_Count()
   at NHibernate.DebugHelpers.CollectionProxy`1.get_Items()
```

---

The interesting gremlin comes here. I've set breakpoint on setter line of `PressJobRun` property.

- if I step over it and quick watch `pressJobRunField`, I see the "*illegal access to loading exception*".
- if I first quick watch `value` variable, I see the loaded collection. Stepping over setter line works as expected.

---

What I use

- Visual Studio 2012, targeting .NET 4
- NHibernate 3.3.1.400
- SQL CE 4
- Castle
- Castle AutoTx facitlity
- I manage session per WCF request myself

---

What I've tried

- disabling lazy loading
- made sure that session is open, and that it's same session during execution of offending code
- toggled `Inverted` map of collection (thought I believe it should be inverted)
- cleaned and rebuilt solution
- made sure in Configuration Manager that all projects in solution are being built
- set debugger to break on all thrown exceptions. Debugger doesn't break with exception that i see set in collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that when `PressJobRub.Department` property is set, my code also adds the `PressJobRun` to appropriate collection in `Department`. I did initialize the collection, but problem was that the collection which NHibernate uses fails for some reason when calling `Contains()` method. I'm still in wonder about gremlin I described in the question, and why the debugger didn't break on exception when I unticked '*Enable just my code debugging*' and set it to break on *Thrown* exceptions too.

Anyhow, solution is to map `PressJobRun.Department` access to field (in my case to `Access.PascalCaseField(Prefix.mUnderscore)`) in order to avoid call that adds the entity to `Department.PressJobRun` collection.

[Krzysztof Kozmic's article](http://kozmic.pl/2009/05/13/two-way-one-to-many-associations-in-nhibernate/) explained this, although in my case collection wasn't uninitialized.